# Paid Proxy for connecting to webdrivers in java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, proxy

i want to connect to webdrivers through proxy networks. Even paid proxies to be use is acceptable, but how to integrate it in web driver. except firefox, i used tor for firefox.

Answer (score 1):

For Chrome -

This is in Python, you can port it to Java

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxy)
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

For PhantomJS -

```
service_args = ['--proxy=%s' % PROXY, '--proxy-type=http']
phantomBinary = "C:\\phantomjs.exe"
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=phantomBinary, service_args=service_args)
```

Comment: not chrome, i need for phantomjs and html unit driver.